# Implement the Combine function using templates

Tags: c++, templates

any idea on how to do it for template? thanks

For example, `Combine(<list containing 6,3,1,9,7>, std::plus<int>())`
should calculate `((((6+3)+1)+9)+7)`.

```
Combine(const Container& c, Function fn) throw (NotEnoughElements)
{
   your code goes here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`return`[`std::accumulate`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/accumulate.html)`(c.begin()+1, c.end(), *(c.begin()), fn);`

(Error handling is left as exercise for OP and reader.)

Comment: Thanks! How do we handle overflow (say large number sum) and overloading (say char type)? sry im not so experienced in template

Comment: @gkid123: `std::plus` cannot handle overflow. You need to write your own safe "plus" struct. Overloading is automatic.